# jQuery .load() event cancelled after clicking on element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading a new hi-res image with the class of `.streamedImage`  on zoom of my low res image. Whenever I begin to load the `.streamedImage`, I place the low res `.previousImage` as a placeholder stacked above the `.streamedImage`. This is so that there is always an image visible, and whenever the hi-res is finished loading, the `.previousImage` is removed and the hi-res is visible.

**Javascript**

```
jQuery('.streamedImage'+imgNum).load(function() {
     jQuery('.previousImage').remove();
     jQuery('.loadingDiv').remove();
     console.log('loaded');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="dialogPreviousImage1" class="previousImage cursorDrag" processid="372014134361312" 
     src="dialogImageStreamer.php?doc=Vortex/inProc/1438/372014134361312/imageLarge12.jpg&userName=jcAdmin&processId=372014134361312&mode=hires&x0=0&y0=0&x1=599.017&y1=791.633&resol=5.7">
<img id="dialogImage1" class="streamedImage1 cursorDrag" processid="372014134361312" 
     src="dialogImageStreamer.php?doc=Vortex/inProc/1438/372014134361312/imageLarge12.jpg&userName=jcAdmin&processId=372014134361312&mode=hires&x0=0&y0=0&x1=599.017&y1=791.633&resol=8.7">`
```

The method above works fine unless I click on the low-res `.previousImage` while the `.streamedImage` is loading. Why would clicking on this element interrupt my `.load` functionality? If I wait until the `.streamedImage` is finished loading, it runs the `.load` functionality fine.

Is there something I can do to avoid this problem?

**I have also tried the below code with the same problem:**

```
jQuery('.streamedImage'+imgNum).on('load', function(){
   jQuery('.previousImage').remove();
   jQuery('.loadingDiv').remove();
})
```

**SOLUTION:**

Guys, thank you for your help I would not have gotten here without it.

Whenever another tool was selected in my GUI, I ran a js function labeled `softproof.disableZoom()`. Within this function, I ran `.unbind();` on the image. This in turn was preventing my pending load event from firing.

I needed to specifically `.unbind('click'); instead of`.unbind()`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the second click triggers another load event, which cancels the first.

Perhaps you could add an attribute to the image to signify that you are mid way through the loading, and if you detect that attribute in subsequent events, ignore the click? Something like:

```
$('.previousImage').on('click', function(e) {

    if( $(this).data('loading') == true ) {
        return false;
    }

    $(this).data('loading', true);

    /* your loading logic */
});
```

Comment: That would be a great solution, but I have to allow clicks on the `.previousImage` while the `.streamedImage` is loading. I have a densitometer tool that retrieves color information from a selected x,y coordinate when clicked on the image. So I want to allow the user to still be able to perform these actions.

Comment: Is there some type of watcher I can run that keeps checking to see if the `.streamedImage` is loaded?

Comment: Could you not just use my code to stop the second load happening, and and still perform your other logic? Instead of returning false if the load is happening, wrap your logic inside the if and check that loading is false.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any event handlers bound to any parent elements? Maybe the click is propagating to a parent and it's that which is interrupting things. You could stop this by using [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

```
$('.previousImage').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Yes. Whenever the user selects the color picker, a .click is applied to that image so that I can draw the reading.

Comment: AFAIK, clicking doesn't stop a pending load event firing, so you should check anywhere you bind to load, and ensure you're not returning false unless absolutely necessary. If you really need to cancel an events default behaviour, use event.preventDefault() which will still allow unrelated handlers for the same event to be executed. That's all I can suggest without seeing some more of your code.

Comment: Ok thanks I will work on this and reply when I've come to a solution. I appreciate the help from the both of you.

Comment: Would an unbind ran on the same element prevent the pending load event from firing?

Comment: Whenever I enable my zoom tool, I add a `.click` to the image to perform the zoom action. Whenever the zoom tool is disabled, I run an `unbind()`; on the image. 

A user activates the zoom tool & requests a hires image when the low res img is clicked. Whenever the zoom tool is activated, a `.click()` is added to perform the zoom action. Whenever my color picker tool is activated, we run `.unbind()` on the image for the zoom tool, and bind a new `.click()` on the image for the color picker tool. It seems as if this method of adding .click and .unbind is what's causing my problem.

Comment: If you use unbind without arguments it will unbind all handlers for all events on that element so they won't be run. If you need to unbind certain events or handlers only you can specify them in your call to unbind. E.g. unbind('click');

Comment: Yes, thanks Tom I just came upon that revelation. I appreciate your help.